# SVG 404 not found using Single Spa and Angular

Tags: angular, frontend, single-spa, single-spa-angular

When I refresh the page, I see in network that there is an error of 404 not found for the svg.

I'm trying to import an svg from an external file in assets/icons, like this.

`<img src="../assets/icons/save.svg" />`

The path is correct, but when I refresh the page, I see in network that there is an error of 404 not found for the svg. I also putted the path in angular.json but still not work.

I'm in Single Spa and using Angular.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: `<img src="assets/icons/save.svg" />`. Remember, Angular create a "dist" folder with the index.html and the .js and a folder assets that it's copy of your assets folder. From the index.html you see the assets folder from `assets` **not** from `../assets`. You can see also if you think that can **not** depend if your component is in one folder or in s folder inside another forlder or...

Comment: What version of Angular are you using?

Comment: @MarkClark I'm using 15.0.0 version of Angular.

Comment: Did you try without the `../` as @Eliseo suggested?

Comment: The generated URL needs to account the server.  I don't know if you are using Vite or not.  When using Vite, we specify a base configuration property that is used to re-write asset URL's.  It is a well-documented trick in the single-spa website.  What are you using to bundle/serve the angular micro-frontend?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I just used another way to import image, using ID on container and import the svg from css:

```css
#logo {
    background-image: url('../assets/icons/save.svg');
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
}
```

```html
    <div id="logo"></div>
```

Comment: it's the same **NOT** use `../assets/icons` else `assets/icons/...` do you understand why? build your application and see the "dist" folder. see where is the .css and where is the assets folder. Check the index.html. The images in .css are relative to the folder where is.